# exit while loop to read button

Tags: android, bluetooth

In this sketch the Arduino connects to an Android app and receive data through a bluetooth connection. It works as intended, but the sketch is getting stuck in the while loop if the bluetooth is not connected and the sketch is not receiving serial data. It works just fine if the bluetooth is connected, and it is receiving serial data, but I can't figure out how to make the sketch break the while loop so it can read the button state. I need the sketch to break the while loop to read the button state. Anybody have any ideas? The data received looks like these examples:
L178:
R215:
L-125:
R-115:
There is always either an L or R followed by a - sign or no minus sign followed by numbers -255 to 255 followed always by a :

```
char myChar = 'a';
String string;
char LorR;

int M2INA = 8;   //left
int M2INB = 7;
int M2PWM = 9;

int M1INA = 11;  //right
int M1INB = 12;
int M1PWM = 10;

int ledB = A2;
int ledR = A3;
int button = 2;

int buttonState;
int val;
int mode = 0;

void setup() {

  pinMode(M1INA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(M1INB, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(M2INA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(M2INB, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(M1PWM, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(M2PWM, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledB, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledR, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(57600);  //230400  460800   921600

  buttonState = digitalRead(button);   // read the initial state
}

void loop() {
  val = digitalRead(button);      // read input value and store it in val

  if (val != buttonState) {          // the button state has changed!
    if (val == LOW) {                // check if the button is pressed
      if (mode == 0) {          // light is off
        mode = 1;               // light is on!

      } else {
        mode = 0;               // light is on!

      }
    }
  }
  buttonState = val;                 // save the new state in our variable
  if (mode == 0) {
    btMode();
  }
  if (mode == 1) {
    followMode();
  }

}

void followMode() {
  digitalWrite (ledR, HIGH);
  digitalWrite (ledB, LOW);
    }


void btMode() {
  digitalWrite (ledR, LOW);
  digitalWrite (ledB, HIGH);

    string = "";
    //Add to string

    while (true) {

      myChar = Serial.read();
      if (32 <= myChar && myChar <= 127) {
        string += myChar;
      }
      if (myChar == ':'){
        break;

    }// While End
    }
    //Analyse string
    if (string != "off:" && string != "on:") {
      if (string != "L0:" && string != "R0:") {
        //code for setting motor left or right
        if (string[0] == 'L') {
          LorR = 'L';
        } else {
          LorR = 'R';
        }
        string.remove(0, 1);
        //code for putting it in reverse
        if (string[0] == '-') {
          string.remove(0, 1);
          string.remove((string.length() - 1), 1);
          //Serial.println(string);
          if (LorR == 'L') {
            //digitalWrite(M2EN, HIGH);
            digitalWrite (M2INA, LOW);
            digitalWrite (M2INB, HIGH);
            analogWrite(M2PWM, string.toInt());

          } else {                           //Reverse left
            //digitalWrite(M1EN, HIGH);
            digitalWrite (M1INA, LOW);
            digitalWrite (M1INB, HIGH);
            analogWrite(M1PWM, string.toInt());
          }
        } else {
          string.remove((string.length() - 1), 1);
          if (LorR == 'L') {
            //digitalWrite(M2EN, HIGH);
            digitalWrite (M2INA, HIGH);
            digitalWrite (M2INB, LOW);
            analogWrite(M2PWM, string.toInt());

          } else {
            digitalWrite (M1INA, HIGH);
            digitalWrite (M1INB, LOW);
            analogWrite(M1PWM, string.toInt());
          }
        }
      } else {
        allStop();
      }

    }//End of long if statment
    if (string == "on:") {

    }
    if (string == "off:") {

    }    
  }


void allStop () {  //coast
  analogWrite(M1PWM, 0);
  analogWrite(M2PWM, 0);
  digitalWrite(M1INA, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(M2INA, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(M1INB, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(M2INB, HIGH);
}
```

Comment: You should read about the versatility of the `if` statement, specifically `else` and `else if`. As for your sketch, I've never programmed for Arduino but I'd recommend checking the status of bluetooth connection in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I could not break the while loop to read the button, but this now works. I changed this

```
while (true) {
```

to

```
while (mode == 0) {
readButton();
```

and cleaned up the sketch a little. here is the final:

```
char myChar = 'a';
String string;
char LorR;

int M2INA = 8;   //left
int M2INB = 7;
int M2PWM = 9;

int M1INA = 11;  //right
int M1INB = 12;
int M1PWM = 10;

int ledB = A2;
int ledR = A3;
int button = 2;

int buttonState;
int val;
int mode = 0;

unsigned long previousButtonMillis=0;
const int buttonInterval = 50; // number of millisecs between button reading
unsigned long previousSerialReadMillis=0;
const int serialReadInterval = 10; // number of millisecs between button reading

void setup() {

  pinMode(M1INA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(M1INB, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(M2INA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(M2INB, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(M1PWM, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(M2PWM, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledB, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledR, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(57600);  //230400  460800   921600

  buttonState = digitalRead(button);   // read the initial state
}

void loop() {

  readButton();
  if (mode == 0) {
    btMode();
  }
  if (mode == 1) {
    followMode();
  }

}

void readButton() {
   if (millis() - previousButtonMillis >= buttonInterval) {   
  val = digitalRead(button);      // read input value and store it in val
  if (val != buttonState) {          // the button state has changed!
    if (val == LOW) {                // check if the button is pressed
      if (mode == 0) {          
        mode = 1;               
      } else {
        mode = 0;               
      }
    }
  } 
  buttonState = val;                 // save the new state in our variable
  previousButtonMillis += buttonInterval;
}
}

void followMode() {
  digitalWrite (ledR, HIGH);
  digitalWrite (ledB, LOW);
}

void btMode() {
  digitalWrite (ledR, LOW);
  digitalWrite (ledB, HIGH);
if (millis() - previousSerialReadMillis >= serialReadInterval){
  string = "";

  while (mode == 0) {
    readButton();
    myChar = Serial.read();
    if (32 <= myChar && myChar <= 127) {
      string += myChar;
    }
    if (myChar == ':') {
      break;
    }
  }
  previousSerialReadMillis += serialReadInterval;
  } // While End
  analyseString();
}

void  analyseString() {

  if (string != "L0:" && string != "R0:") {
    //code for setting motor left or right
    if (string[0] == 'L') {
      LorR = 'L';
    } else {
      LorR = 'R';
    }
    string.remove(0, 1);
    //code for putting it in reverse
    if (string[0] == '-') {
      string.remove(0, 1);
      string.remove((string.length() - 1), 1);
      if (LorR == 'L') {
        digitalWrite (M2INA, LOW);
        digitalWrite (M2INB, HIGH);
        int leftPWM = string.toInt();
        if (leftPWM > 80) {
          leftPWM = 80;
        }
        analogWrite(M2PWM, leftPWM);

      } else {                           //Reverse left
        digitalWrite (M1INA, LOW);
        digitalWrite (M1INB, HIGH);
        int rightPWM = string.toInt();
        if (rightPWM > 80) {
          rightPWM = 80;
        }
        analogWrite(M1PWM, rightPWM);
      }
    } else {
      string.remove((string.length() - 1), 1);
      if (LorR == 'L') {
        digitalWrite (M2INA, HIGH);
        digitalWrite (M2INB, LOW);
        analogWrite(M2PWM, string.toInt());

      } else {
        digitalWrite (M1INA, HIGH);
        digitalWrite (M1INB, LOW);
        analogWrite(M1PWM, string.toInt());
      }
    }
  } else {
    allStop();
  }
  //End of long if statment
}

void allStop () {

  analogWrite(M1PWM, 125);
  analogWrite(M2PWM, 125);
  digitalWrite(M1INA, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(M2INA, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(M1INB, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(M2INB, HIGH);
}
```